# ms-access client server configuration

Tags: ms-access

How can I easily set the path for the front end to connect to the backend database.  Do I have to use the linked table manager every time ?

I found a tool [here](http://btabdevelopment.com/free-access-tools/) but it isn't very reliable.  There is no simple config to set the back end path ?

Comment: Do you want to use MS-Access as the front-end and an ODBC compatible SQL database (MySQL, MS-SQLserver, Oracle ...) as the back-end?

Comment: @MartijnvanderJagt No it's just a Front end access file with the forms and queries and a backend access file with the tables.  I'm trying to do some development work against it (can't set up odbc for some reason).  It seams to be hardcoded to a path F:\FOLDER\etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When importing a table from another MS-Access database you can choose between a 'table' and a 'linked source'. If you now choose the 'linked source' and then you select the file of the other MS-Access file (where you select the table you want to link to ) you will get the table in your front-end Access as a normal table with one new property 'linked table'.

Now you can do everything on the selected data in both Access environments. The data will be synchronised as soon as you enter one record (make a change in one line and go to the next line). You do not need to visit the linked table manager any more at all.